# Topic Challenge #1 – Famous Designers

Tags: discussion, status-completed, challenge

#### For the next two weeks you're challenged to ask [famous-designers](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/famous-designers) questions.

Let's start the [Graphic Design Biweekly Topic Challenge](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3136/52050) with [Famous Designers](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3149/52050).

We'll keep this topic pretty broad... style identification, replicating a particular effect, a particular designer's process, design history, terminology... Anything about famous designers will do; as long as it's on-topic and specific to a particular famous designer.

I'll add some bounties to any questions I think need or deserve it and in two weeks time I'll post an answer here with the stats on how many questions have been asked, how many answers those question have had and anything else notable.

Remember to tag the question [famous-designers](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/famous-designers) otherwise it won't be counted.

If you have any questions, you can ask them [here](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3136/52050) or bring it up in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57292/improving-gdse).

And if you have any more topic suggestions please leave them [here](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3136/52050).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Results

Questions posted:

- [How did Escher make his tesselations?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/90537/52050)

We only had a single question posted, but it was a good one! @PieBie posted the question, which is currently sitting at +20 with over 450 views and single answer from @Raphael, currently at +17. Great question and a great answer!

@Ryan kindly put up a 100 point bounty which wen't to @Raphael's answer too.

Answer (score 6):

So let's kick this thing off then. Someone has to be first, so it might as well be me.

You can find my question here:

[How did Escher make his tesselations?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/90537/how-did-escher-make-his-tesselations)