# Topic Challenge #2 – Font Design

Tags: discussion, status-completed, challenge

#### For the next two weeks you're challenged to ask [font-design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font-design) questions.

The next instalment of the [Graphic Design Biweekly Topic Challenge](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3136/52050) is [Font Design](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3137/52050).

I'd really like to see some non software related questions if possible; anything regarding the design process, critiques, designing for different languages and scripts, working with OpenType features... Anything to do with designing typefaces.

I'll add some bounties to any questions I think need or deserve it and in two weeks time I'll post an answer here with the stats on how many questions have been asked, how many answers those question have had and anything else notable.

Remember to tag the question [font-design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font-design) otherwise it won't be counted.

If you have any questions, you can ask them [here](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3136/52050) or bring it up in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57292/improving-gdse).

Please leave any more topic suggestions [here](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3136/52050).

Comment: Here's my first question for this topic: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/91510/why-is-bounce-and-tumble-rarely-done-these-days

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Results

Questions posted:

- [Is there a general rule regarding font spacing?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/91377/52050)
- [How to create a true type font (.ttf) font from CAD-designed letters?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/91500/52050)
- [Why is Bounce (and Tumble) rarely done these days?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/91510/52050)
- [Why add extrema points when designing fonts?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/92126/52050)
- [What is the rationale and market value for designing a new font face?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/92363/what-is-the-rationale-and-market-value-for-designing-a-new-font-face)

A few more questions this time around...

- The [top scoring question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/91510/52050) (currently sitting at +9) was posted by @Ryan,
- closely followed by [@WELZ's question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/91377/52050) (currently at +7)
- and [my own question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/92126/52050) (which I got in on the last day! currently at +6).
- The [top scoring answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/91512/52050) (currently sitting at +10) was posted by @Metis.