# Topic Challenge #3 – User Interface Design

Tags: discussion, status-completed, challenge

#### For the next two weeks you're challenged to ask [interface-design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interface-design) questions.

The next instalment of the [Graphic Design Biweekly Topic Challenge](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3136/52050) is [User Interface Design](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3152/52050).

In the words of PieBie...

> I cannot start to tell you how many times I've seen a beautifully designed button. But in only one state. No hover, no touch, no active. It's like the button is just decoration, not an actual interaction element. Same goes for inputs, dropdowns, menus, ... Basically everything that's not static.
>
> I think there are some really good questions to be found in the area of user interfaces, interaction and user experience. Questions on best UI practices can be asked over at UXSE, but on how to put these best practices into an overall design belong here.

I'll add some bounties to any questions I think need or deserve it and in two weeks time I'll post an answer here with the stats on how many questions have been asked, how many answers those question have had and anything else notable.

Remember to tag the question [interface-design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interface-design) otherwise it won't be counted.

If you have any questions, you can ask them [here](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3136/52050) or bring it up in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57292/improving-gdse).

You can leave more topic suggestions [here](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3136/52050).

Answer (score 1):

## Results

There were only two [interface-design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interface-design) questions posted during the callenge (and I've a sneaking suspicion those weren't intentionally posted as part of the challenge):

- [How to choose font color against yellow background?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/92863/52050)
- [Ways to practice design as a student without a subject or project](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/92226/52050)

The top scoring question was [How to choose font color against yellow background?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/92863/52050), currently at a score of +2, with [@Metis' answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/92924/52050) to that question being the highest scoring, currently sitting at +4...

I'll chalk the lack of questions up to the moderator elections which ran at the same time as the challenge this time.

Better next time though please folks :)