# Topic Challenge #4 – Print Production

Tags: discussion, challenge

#### For the next two weeks you're challenged to ask [print-production](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/print-production) questions.

The next instalment of the [Graphic Design Biweekly Topic Challenge](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3136/52050) is [Print Production](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3197/52050).

> Print Production is a very technical topic lending itself quite well to our format while being more advanced than many of our questions.
>
> Stuff like how to plan a foil. What is the benefit of a particular printing system (gravure, risograph, lithograph, etc.). Different papers. Profiling. Scoring and Folding. Mixed Media. The list goes on and on.
>
> There's a whole world here that I would suspect not a single person here knows everything about which means any one of us should be curious enough to ask something useful about printing.

I really like this one so I'm looking forward to some interesting questions!

I'll add some bounties to any questions I think need or deserve it and in two weeks time I'll post an answer here with the stats on how many questions have been asked, how many answers those question have had and anything else notable.

Remember to tag the question [print-production](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/print-production) otherwise it won't be counted.

If you have any questions, you can ask them [here](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3136/52050) or bring it up in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57292/improving-gdse).

You can leave more topic suggestions [here](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3136/52050).