# Does Graphic Design have a chat room?

Tags: support, chat

On Stack Overflow there is an option to talk in a chat room on the right hand column when someone needs more details on a question. Does Graphic Design have that option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, it's called [The Ink Spot](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=graphicdesign.stackexchange.com)!

---

There are also [some others](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=graphicdesign.stackexchange.com) including

- [The Spam Blot](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56223/the-spam-blot) so users can see what is auto-flagged by the Smoke Detector
- [The Looking Glass](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36555/the-looking-glass) for showing off your work and having others give feedback
- [Improving GSDE](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57292/improving-gdse) which was recently created to talk about how to improve GDSE based on [this post](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3133/23061)